# Mulitple DllMain in the program how to prevent that

Tags: c++

Today I found an interest thing when I debug a program. There are two DLLMains compiled into the final program. One in the main program, the another in a third party static library. I am using MSVC 2005, the compiler issued no errors/warnings.

My question is - how to prevent this from happening again? We have a dozen static libraries to link.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is why you have static libraries with DLLMain functions?

Comment: Probably the static library has a `#define` or something that causes `DLLMain` to be ignored?

Comment: Generally modules from a static library will only be linked if they are needed to satisfy a missing external symbol. And the linker should complain if there are duplicate symbol definitions in the final output. How do you know there are two DLLMains? That seems impossible to me.